# Trying to create seo friendly url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

I'm trying to create friendly url for my site but with no success :(( and i have two questions

**The first is**: 
How to change the url from [domain.com/page/something.php](http://domain.com/page/something.php) to [domain.com/something](http://domain.com/something)
**And the second is:**
Will the changes make duplicate content and if how to fix the problem.

Thank you for your time,
Have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the official URL Rewriting guide: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

You'll be using the simplest use case, Canonical URLs. Assuming you have no other pages that you need to worry about, you can use a rule like this: (note: untested, your usage may vary)

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)([^/]+)$ /$1$2.php
```

While that example might not *exactly* work for your use case, hopefully reading the guide and my example will help you get you on your way.